# python 2 polygon intersection

Tags: python, intersection, slope, reclassify

I have slope values derived from a DEM which I reclassified into NoDATA and vaules which I need. Then I made a polygon from this raster.

I need to do intersection or something like that with the polygon shapefile of administrative units(towns) and I need to find out which town has potential for the building of a downhill course.(that's why i use slope > 10°) But I need to preserve the shape of the town polygons. When i use arcpy.Interscet its just geometry and the result was just common for both polygons. So maybe i dont need intersect but something similar.